# Is it possible to expose my own methods to C# in a custom native CoreCLR host environment?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, managed, coreclr

I've been following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting) guide to create my own .NET Core 6 host from an unmanaged C++ application using `hostfxr.h` and `nethost.h`, and interface with a managed DLL written in C#. I can retrieve and call C# methods marked with `[UnmanagedCallersOnly]` on the C++ side, but now I would like to do the opposite, and expose unmanaged C++ functions to the managed DLL. I've seen libraries like `System.Math` and the Unity engine use a very elegant solution where they declare methods as extern, and mark them with the `[MethodImpl(InternalCall)]` attribute, and provide the method body in native code. Examples:

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern double Pow(double x, double y); // System.Math

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private extern void set_position_Injected(ref Vector3 value); // Unity Transform class
```

According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/0c88c2e67260ddcb1d400eb6adda19de627998f5/Documentation/mscorlib.md#registering-your-qcall-or-fcall-method) page, the names of these methods must be registered as `QCall`/`FCall`/`ECall` on the unmanaged side, along with the native implementation. However I  haven't been able to find any examples or guides on how this can be achieved. It must be possible somehow, because otherwise that guide wouldn't exist on the official dotnet github, I just can't figure out how to do it.

Just out of curiosity, I tried to define and call an extern method in my DLL with the `InternalCall` attribute and a random name, just to see what error it would throw, and this is what I got:

```cs
System.Security.SecurityException: ECall methods must be packaged into a system module.
```

Unfortunately this wasn't really helpful, as all it did was introduce a third `_Call` name, and made this already confusing topic even more confusing.

Is this even possible, and if it is, how can I access the necessary `FCClassElement`/`FCFuncStart`/`FCFuncEnd`/etc... macros to start exposing my own native methods to a managed C# DLL?

I would like to avoid COM, because as far as I know it's only available on Windows, and I'm trying to create a cross-platform solution.

Comment: It is not an extensible mechanism, you have to modify and rebuild the CLR to add such functions.  Somewhat sensible in the early days of CoreCLR when it was still being adapted to work on the unixes, thus the documentation, today it is unpractical.  Pinvoke with [DllImport] is the way to do it.

Comment: Well I hope they will make it more extensible in the future. C# can be an extremely powerful scripting language in a native C++ app, as proven by the Unity engine.